# Enable auto-complete in Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to turn [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) in the minibuffer:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
```

What I get is `auto-complete` working in the first instance of minibuffer, but no longer. That is the full `minibuffer-setup-hook` after loading:

```
(auto-complete-mode turn-on-visual-line-mode ido-minibuffer-setup rfn-eshadow-setup-minibuffer minibuffer-history-isearch-setup minibuffer-history-initialize)
```

How to turn `auto-complete` on persistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zev called to my attention `auto-complete-mode-maybe`, and that is the required modifications (file `auto-complete.el`, all changes have comments):

```
;; Add this variable
(defcustom ac-in-minibuffer t
  "Non-nil means expand in minibuffer."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'auto-complete)

...

(defun ac-handle-post-command ()
  (condition-case var
      (when (and ac-triggered
                 (not (ido-active)) ;; Disable auto pop-up in ido mode
                 (or ac-auto-start
                     ac-completing)
                 (not isearch-mode))
        (setq ac-last-point (point))
        (ac-start :requires (unless ac-completing ac-auto-start))
        (ac-inline-update))
    (error (ac-error var))))

...

(defun auto-complete-mode-maybe ()
  "What buffer `auto-complete-mode' prefers."
  (if (or (and (minibufferp (current-buffer)) ac-in-minibuffer) ;; Changed
          (memq major-mode ac-modes))
      (auto-complete-mode 1)))
```

And `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
```

Certainly, there are binding conflicts but it is possible to solve them.

Answer (score 7):

You rarely ever want to add a function symbol to a hook variable if that function acts as a toggle (which will be the case for most minor modes).

`minibuffer-setup-hook` runs "just after entry to minibuffer", which means that you would be enabling auto complete mode the first time you enter the minibuffer; disabling it the second time; enabling it the third time; etc...

Typically you would either look to see if there's a pre-defined `turn-on-autocomplete-mode` type of function, or define your own:

```
(defun my-turn-on-auto-complete-mode ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1)) ;; an argument of 1 will enable most modes
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-turn-on-auto-complete-mode)
```

I can't test that, because you haven't linked to the autocomplete-mode you are using.

Comment: Sorry for telling it now, but I'm using cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/. And I've checked the toggling function: it does not work on odd numbers, i.e. it's been disabled after the first instance.

Comment: I am having following error `Symbol’s function definition is void: my-turn-on-auto-complete-mode`

Comment: @alper Evidentially you have evaluated the `add-hook` form but not the `defun` form preceding it.  I suggest typing or pasting the defun into any buffer and then using `C-x C-e` (with the cursor immediately after the final `)` of that form) to evaluate it without the need for a minibuffer; that should deal to the error.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, there are typos in the answer -- I had repeatedly used `autocomplete` instead of `auto-complete`.  You can still use my previous comment, but with the fixed `defun` in the newly-edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @phils: would it also work on `isearch` shell buffer?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  Note that `isearch` doesn't use a minibuffer at all; it displays the current search term in the echo area, but the buffer being searched is the active buffer at all times (unless you use something like `M-e`, which allows you to edit the search term using the minibuffer).

Answer (score 4):

The creator of "auto-complete-mode" explicitly excludes the minibuffer for use with auto completion. The definition for the minor mode is:

```
(define-global-minor-mode global-auto-complete-mode
  auto-complete-mode auto-complete-mode-maybe
  :group 'auto-complete)
```

so the "turn mode on" function is "auto-complete-mode-maybe" - the definition of that function is:

```
(defun auto-complete-mode-maybe ()
  "What buffer `auto-complete-mode' prefers."
  (if (and (not (minibufferp (current-buffer)))
           (memq major-mode ac-modes))
      (auto-complete-mode 1)))
```

This function explicitly tests in the if statement if the current-buffer is the minibuffer and doesn't turn on the auto-complete-mode if it is.

If you want to use auto-complete-mode in the minibuffer, you should probably contact the maintainer of the mode and ask him why he excluded the minibuffer and what programming changes he feels are necessary to enable the mode in the minibuffer.

Comment: Thank, zev! I wrote the solution and now waiting for 5 hours to post it (reputation limit).

Comment: @anton: I don't think there's a time limit for voting up an answer that is useful for you - if this was a helpful answer, click it!